# Действие с выбранным объектом в ng-options

Tags: angularjs

Разбираюсь с ng-options.
Сейчас все в таком виде:

```
<select ng-required="1" ng-model="modelName" ng-options="element.id as name for (name, element) in elements" ng-change="elementChanged();">
    <option value="">Не выбрано</option>
</select>
```

`elements` имеет примерно такой вид:

```
{
    Name1: {id: 1, ...params...},
    Name2: {id: 2, ...params...},
    ...
}
```

Мне нужно передать в функцию `element`, в виде объекта. При этом нельзя менять модель на объект, только его идентификатор (т.е. при обращении к модели, я получу всего лишь строку).

Есть ли возможность обработки выбранного объекта, при использовании `ng-options`, без использования модели?

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо изменить директиву ngOptions на `ng-options="element as name for (name, element) in elements"`, тогда выводится будут "имена", а модель хранить объект

Comment: Как я уже написал, это не подходит. Мне нужно в модели хранить идентификатор.

Comment: Как вариант, можно внутри функции elementChanged искать по значению модели элемент в объекте.